Simplify in closed-form $\sum_n P_n(0)^2 r^n P_n(\cos \theta)$
Simplify in a closed form the sum $$S(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(0)^2 r^n P_n(\cos \theta)$$ where $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial and $0<r<1$. Note that $P_n(0)= 0$ for odd $n$ and $P_n(0)= (-1)^n(2n-1)!!/(2n)!!$ for even $n$. Further, note that for $\cos\theta = 1$ it simplifies as $$S(r,0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_{2n}(0)^2 r^{2n} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2 r^{2n} = \frac{2}{\pi} K(r)$$ where $K(k)$ is the elliptic integral of the second kind, which is the generating function of $\frac{\pi}{2}P_{2n}(0)^2$.
Is there a way to evaluate the infinite sum for arbitrary $\cos\theta$? If not, is there an approximate solution or at least a nice way to express this as a real integral? What is the asymptotics close to $r=1$?

You want the Closed Form of,
$$S(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{r^{2n}P_{2n}(\cos \theta)}{2^{4n}}$$
$S(r,\pi /2)$ can be written in terms of Elliptic Integral too.
Also,
$$\sqrt{2}S(1,x)={_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{1-\cos x}{2}\right]}{_2F_1\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right]}$$
I am not sure what the entire closed form will be.

Can we use the asymptotics of $P_{2n}(0)^2 = \frac1\pi n^{-1} - \frac1{4\pi} n^{-2}  + \mathcal{O}(n^{-3})$ to obtain a simple approximate solution? We can eliminate odd terms as $S(r,\theta)=\frac12[S(r,\theta)+S(-r,\theta)]$, so to leading order $$\frac{dS}{dr} = \frac12\left[\frac1{\pi r}\sum_n r^n P_{n}(x) + \frac1{\pi r}\sum_n (-r)^n P_{n}(x) \right] = \frac1{2\pi r} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xr + r^2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2xr + r^2}}\right]$$ plus small $n$ terms (finite many of them) where $x=\cos\theta$.

To express the series as an integral, one can use the generating function for the product of two Legendre polynomials derived by Leonard C. Maximon here:
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{p=0}^\infty t^{p}P_p(\cos\theta_1)P_p(\cos\theta_2)=\frac2\pi\frac{\mathbf K\left( 2\sqrt{\frac{t\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{t^2-2t\cos\left( \theta_1+\theta_2 \right)+1}} \right)}{\sqrt{t^2-2t\cos\left( \theta_1+\theta_2 \right)+1}}
\end{equation}
As (Gradshteyn&Ryzhik (7.221.3))
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}P_{2n}(\cos s)\,ds=2^{-4n}\binom{2n}n^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \int_0^{2\pi}P_{2n+1}(\cos s)\,ds=0
\end{equation}
by taking $\theta_1=\theta,\theta_2=s$, we have
\begin{align}
 S(r,\theta)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-4n}\binom{2n}{n}^2r^{2n}P_{2n}(\cos \theta)\\
 &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\,ds\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^nP_{n}(\cos \theta)P_{n}(\cos s)\\
 &=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathbf K\left( 2\sqrt{\frac{r\sin\theta \sin s}{r^2-2r\cos\left( \theta+s \right)+1}} \right)}{\sqrt{r^2-2r\cos\left( \theta+s \right)+1}}\,ds
\end{align}
which seems to be numerically correct.

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.
For $S(\theta)$, we only need to sum over even indices since $P_n(0)=0$ for odd $n$.
Additionally, as seen here, $$P_{2n}(0)=(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=(-1)^n\frac 2 \pi \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\cos^{2n} x \,dx$$
Thus
$$S(\theta) = \frac 4 {\pi^2}\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} r^{2n} \cos^{2n}(x)\cos^{2n}(y)P_{2n}(\cos \theta)\,dxdy$$
Using the generating function for Legendre polynomials and the fact that $P_n(-u)=(-1)^nP_n(u)$,
$$2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{2n}(u)t^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{n}(u)t^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} P_{n}(-u)t^{n}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-2ut+t^2}} + \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+2ut+t^2}}$$
$$\begin{split}
S(\theta) &= \frac 2 {\pi^2} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac 1 {\sqrt{1 - 2r\cos x\cos y\cos \theta+r^2\cos^2x\cos^2y}}dx dy\\
& + \frac 2 {\pi^2} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac 1 {\sqrt{1 + 2r\cos x\cos y\cos \theta+r^2\cos^2x\cos^2y}}dx dy
\end{split}$$
